# Orchard CMS- Get the current Data Migration Record version number

Tags: orchardcms

Given the name of a Migrations class as a string, how can I get the current version number as stored in Orchard_Framework_DataMigrationRecord?

I can see Version in IExtensionManager, but that appears to just be the module version as defined in module.txt.

Comment: What do you need that for?

Comment: Good question- I'm extending the Command Line tools with a couple of helpers; one of which is a command to stub out the classes, methods and files to create a new widget, similar to the codegen module. I need to know which migration version the module is on, so that I can create the UpdateFromX() method (where X is the current version + 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I've solved this myself-

I knew that Orchard must already be executing similar code to what I require when it fires off migration methods, so I created a new migrations file, and put a breakpoint on the Create() method. When the breakpoint hit, I looked up through the call stack to find DataMigrationManager in Orchard.Data.Migration. Everything I needed was in there, and if anyone else has similar requirements, I suggest they have a look at that class as a starting point.

This is pretty much lifted straight out of that class:

```
        string moduleName="Your.Module.Name";
        var migrations = GetDataMigrations(moduleName);

        // apply update methods to each migration class for the module
        var current = 0;
        foreach (var migration in migrations)
        {
            // copy the objet for the Linq query
            var tempMigration = migration;

            // get current version for this migration
            var dataMigrationRecord = GetDataMigrationRecord(tempMigration);

            if (dataMigrationRecord != null)
            {
                current = dataMigrationRecord.Version.Value;
            }

            // do we need to call Create() ?
            if (current == 0)
            {
                // try to resolve a Create method

                var createMethod = GetCreateMethod(migration);
                if (createMethod != null)
                {
                    //create method has been written, but not executed!
                    current = (int)createMethod.Invoke(migration, new object[0]);
                }
            }
        }
        Context.Output.WriteLine("Version: {0}", current);
```

A couple of methods you may need:

```
    private DataMigrationRecord GetDataMigrationRecord(IDataMigration tempMigration)
    {
        return _dataMigrationRepository.Table
            .Where(dm => dm.DataMigrationClass == tempMigration.GetType().FullName)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }

    private static MethodInfo GetCreateMethod(IDataMigration dataMigration)
    {
        var methodInfo = dataMigration.GetType().GetMethod("Create", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (methodInfo != null && methodInfo.ReturnType == typeof(int))
        {
            return methodInfo;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Don't forget to inject any dependencies that you may need.

Comment: Oh and something else- I was under the impression that each module has one migration number. I now believe that to be incorrect- a module can have multiple migration classes, and the version number refers to each class